# rails check for existing instance attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, not-exists

I'm working on a social networking site (basically a copy of facebook to be honest...) and I reused big parts of insoshi. But the feed of insoshi is not accurate enough for my likings. As in it doesnt support more specialized messages. You will see what I mean in the following 
code:

```
item = activity.item
relationship = relationship(item)
case relationship
   when 1
     raw %(<p>You wrote on your own wall: <br/>
     #{truncate(item.body, :length => 20)}</p>)
   when 2
     raw %(<p>#{link_to item.user.name, item.user} wrote on your wall</p>)
   when 3
     raw %(<p>#{link_to item.user.name, item.user} wrote on his wall</p>)
   when 4
     raw %(<p>You wrote on #{link_to item.user.name, item.user}'s wall</p>)
   when 5
     raw %(<p>#{link_to item.user.name, item.user} wrote on 
              #{link_to item.contact.name, item.contact}'s wall</p>)
end

    def relationship(item) 
        unless item.owner.nil?
          contact = item.owner #so that it works for posts as well
        else
          contact = item.contact
        end
        user = item.user

        if current_user != contact or current_user != user
          return 5
        else
          if current_user == contact
            if current_user == user
              return 1
            else
              return 2
            end
          else
            if contact == user
              return 3
            else
              return 4
            end
          end
        end
end
```

I have different types of items. Normally items have a "user" and a "contact". Except posts, they have a "user" and an "owner". Because the other of a post can write it on somebody's wall (therefor the owner).

Now the problem arises as soon as I try to set the contact to the item.contact... it just keeps bugging me with 'NoMethod' error saying that item.contact does not exist. (which is obvious if the item is a post and not a 'connection' or comparable).

So I am asking for your opinion:
1) Fix the problem with some more ruby, or
2) change the post model so that a post has a 'user' and a 'contact'?

Thanks guys
Stefano

Comment: Uargh. Please use Symbols instead of Integers.

Comment: I hate to be a dick, but this code is really difficult to follow and looks very hacky. I would definitely not fix the problem by adding more code to this. I would recommend reading up on Single table inheritance, polymorphism, and think about moving `relationship` to a model.

Comment: make a new model including a table purely for the purpose of customizing the output of a helper? @Tass: would symbols not make it more confusing? :user_same_as_contact, :current_user_same_as_user i'm not sure if i get what you mean.

Comment: @Stefano, I wasn't aware that this was a helper. I would definitely move this logic to a model. That will make it easier to test and document.

Comment: @Beerlington I agree with you, but how would this be done? because the relationship depends on who views the post, who wrote it, and on who's wall it is...

Comment: @Stefano, I added a recommended refactor for your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your logic, relationships 3 and 4 would never get returned. I think where you have `current_user != contact or current_user != user`, you meant to have `and`. Personally, I always use && because it short circuits if the first condition is false. However, in my refactor, you don't need it because it returns 5 if no other cases match.

I moved the relationship logic to the Item model and made appropriate updates in the helper.

## View Helper:

```
case item.relationship_to_user(current_user)
when 1
  raw %(<p>You wrote on your own wall: <br/>
  #{truncate(item.body, :length => 20)}</p>)
when 2
  raw %(<p>#{link_to item.user.name, item.user} wrote on your wall</p>)
when 3
  raw %(<p>#{link_to item.user.name, item.user} wrote on his wall</p>)
when 4
  raw %(<p>You wrote on #{link_to item.user.name, item.user}'s wall</p>)
when 5
  raw %(<p>#{link_to item.user.name, item.user} wrote on 
  #{link_to item.contact.name, item.contact}'s wall</p>)
end
```

## Item Class

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  def relationship_to_user(current_user)
    contact = owner || contact  

    return 1 if current_user == contact && current_user == user
    return 2 if current_user == contact
    return 3 if current_user != contact
    return 4 if current_user != contact && contact != user

    return 5
    # return 5 if current_user != contact or current_user != user
  end

end
```

Comment: thanks, greatly appreciated. but it seems that the integer keys are the way to go(?)

Comment: You can easily improve it by using constants or symbols. `Relationship::FRIENDS` or `:friends`

Answer (score 0):

I would fix with Ruby code.

`contact = item.contact if item.respond_to? :contact`

By using respond_to? this will work for any class that has a contact.